# How do I figure out the number of folders in a directory(not subdirectories)

Tags: python

I have the following code which works but it searches in all the sub-directories,I only want to search in the immediate directory and also limit the search for folders,I don't need the files cound,can anyone suggest how to do that?

```
import os

files = folders = 0

path = "\\\\snowcone\\builds708\\INTEGRATION\\CI_LA.UM.5.7-45903-8x98.1-4\\LINUX\\android\\out\\target\\product"

for _, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
  # ^ this idiom means "we won't be using this value"
    files += len(filenames)
    folders += len(dirnames)

print "{:,} files, {:,} folders".format(files, folders)
```

Comment: If you don't want to descend into sub-directories, why are you walking the file tree instead of just listing the files?

Comment: @Falmarri - what should I use then?I dont need to list the file count aswell,I only need folder count

Answer (score 4):

You can do this instead

```
import os
len([i for i in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(i)])
```

Or as recommended (saves from creating list):

```
import os
sum(os.path.isdir(i) for i in os.listdir(path))
```

Comment: I have a path(dir) as input..I need to use that

Comment: Creating a list to get its length is overkill. It might be OK in this case but it's not a good idea in general. Prefer `sum(os.path.isdir(i) for i in os.listdir('.'))`.

Comment: @JeffShort You can replace `'.'` with `path`.

Comment: I did something like `folders = sum(os.path.isdir(i) for i in os.listdir(path))
print folders` which prints `0` eventhough it has 2 folders

Comment: does sum work with python 2.7.x ,it prints the list of folders correctly but the `sum` doesn't seem to be working

Comment: found the bug `os.listdir(path)` is just listing the folder but not the whole dir path

Comment: You'll have to do the following to get it working:
`sum(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, i)) for i in os.listdir(path))`

Answer (score 0):

Well even though a very good answer has already been given to you, here's another one just for the sake of it. I reckon the solution is less elegant and less efficient though.

```
import os

path = 'your_path_goes_here'
number_of_dirs = len(list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(path))))
```