# Check amount of folders in a directory (without files or subfolders)

Tags: python, directory

I need to see how many folders are in a directory, but so that I don't count the files or subfolders.

I have tried:

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/[Name]/Desktop/python_testing/my_folder"
num = sum(os.path.isdir(i) for i in os.listdir(path))
print(num)
```

num returns 0, even though it should return 2 (the amount of folders in my_folder).
The method I tried is from [How do I figure out the number of folders in a directory(not subdirectories)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273956/how-do-i-figure-out-the-number-of-folders-in-a-directorynot-subdirectories).

Comment: Can you share the directory tree of the folder

Comment: If you are working on Windows there is really no need to change the path to the Unix convention. The platform-independent way to do that is `path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"my_folder")`. And if you are getting unexpected results you should maybe check that the value of `os.getcwd()` is what you think it is, because it often differs from what novices expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('path/to/root/folder')
num = sum(p.is_dir() for p in path.iterdir())
print(num)
```